# trying to send urdu string view to controller using ajax call but it always null on control

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

trying to **post some data and a single urdu templates** from view to controller using ajax call i've check it through jquery alert it show exact same urdu template there in view while sending but when i check on controller **except urdu** all data is available urdu field is always null ,
can anyone help me in this regard .
is it correct i can't send urdu and i need to convert it hex then send hex string to controller ? or there is any work around to send urdu from view to controller so i can easily convert urdu to hex in code behind .

```
function SaveConfig() {
    alert(urdumessage)
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UrduTemp", "Setup")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'Id':Id,
            'Description': Description,
            'Urdu_Description: urduDescription,
            'CategoryId': CategoryId,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
        }
    });
}
```

in controller :

```
 public ActionResult UrduTemp(UpdateConfig Data)
    {
        try
        {
                var a =Request["urduDescription"];
                var resp= push.UpdateConfiguration(Data, LoginId);       
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { ErrorCode = "-99", Users = "Error : "+ ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
public class UpdateConfig
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string urdu_Description{ get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Thank you all its done i've just post with ***form*** from view and all values are available in controller.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code.

Comment: @MoeinMohammadian coded added

Comment: stringify your data object that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug. There is no field urduDescription in your code.

try to replace

```
   var a =Request["urduDescription"];
```

with

```
  var a = Data.urdu_Description;
```

Comment: my problem is **Data.urdu_Description** is always null that' why I'm trying to get **urduDescription ** using request .